# Handling Perl SOAP Web Service Result

Tags: perl, soap

I am calling a web service, customer verifies that call is successful which means my data reached their server succsessfully. But unfortutanetely I could not read output.
This is the first time I encountered. I worked with SOAP web services for many years.

I am calling web service as follows which is very common

```
my $som = $soap->call(
  .............................
);
```

I am trying to get result as follow but it did not work

```
my $result = $som->result;
```

I can see result when I call web service by using SOAPUI:

```xml
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <WebServiceOutput xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/keyword/firm/method">
         <OUTPUT1>string1</OUTPUT1>
         <OUTPUT2>string2</OUTPUT2>
         <OUTPUT3>string3</OUTPUT3>
      </WebServiceOutput>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I also Dumped `$som` but it does not include result above. I am waiting to see term `string1`, `string2` but it does not exist

How can I handle result?

Comment: What is the result you actually get?  Then on warnings and see if anything pops.

Comment: There's not enough in your question to be able to answer it. Please see [ask] for what makes a good question. At the very least an [mcve] is useful.

Comment: This probably won't be much help, but I'm told that these days people prefer [XML::Compile](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Compile) over SOAP::Lite. Me, I just avoid working with SOAP :-/

Comment: When I dump $som, I see nested hash and arrays but none of them includes the result. I can see result when calling via SOAP:UI at the format I wrote at my first message. Those should be visible when I dump $som but they are not

Answer (score 1):

I have another web service from same customer which works successfully. So I compared with it and realized a small difference which caused problem.

My wsdl address is: http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:8080/orawsv/company/method?wsdl

I was calling as follow, proxy value includes "wsdl". When I removed it from proxy value, I could get result with code $som->result.

```
my $soap = SOAP::Lite
    -> on_action( sub { join '/', @_ } )
    -> readable(1)
    -> uri($uri)
    -> proxy("http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:8080/orawsv/company/method?wsdl")
    -> ns("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/","soapenv");
```

But I could not understand why it was needed removing "?wsdl" tag from proxy value because I was always adding it at my previous works.